# How can a last implicit row have a different height?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Working on a CSS Grid example that contains several photo cards (items). Let's imagine that these items are created dynamically by any server-side logic.

The last item in the grid container is a div element defined as a footer for that grid, which also contains a button that has to be center-aligned inside its parent.

By the grid definition, the footer takes the height of the implicit row: 200px. The footer element spans the 2 columns of the grid.

How can the footer, being in the last implicit row, have a smaller size than the `grid-auto-rows` property, defined on the grid container?

```css
.travel-photos {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 20px 10px;
}

.travel-photos h1 {
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.photo-card>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.photos-footer {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<section class="travel-photos">
  <h1>PHOTOS</h1>

  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>

  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>

  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>

  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>

  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>

  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>
  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>


  <div class="photos-footer">
    <button>MORE</button>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`grid-auto-rows`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks) property only accepts track sizes as values. It does not accept any form of syntax that would allow you to target a particular row.

Therefore, another method is needed to size the grid item appearing in the last implicit row.

Here's a simple solution: *Target the last item directly.*

```
.photos-footer {
    height: 50px;
}
```

And then, because you want the content of that item (the button) centered, use flexbox:

```
.photos-footer {
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here's the full code:

```css
.travel-photos {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 20px 10px;
}

.travel-photos h1 {
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.photo-card > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.photos-footer {
    height: 50px;
    align-self: end;  /* align item to bottom of row */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<section class="travel-photos">
  <h1>PHOTOS</h1>
  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>
  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>
  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>
  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>
  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>
  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>
  <div class="photo-card">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>
  <div class="photos-footer">
    <button>MORE</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

***NOTE*** that this solution doesn't actually change the height of the last grid row, which remains at 200px, per the `grid-auto-rows` rule. This solution changes only the height of the grid item inside the last row. That's why there's a gap between the penultimate row and the grid item pinned to the bottom of the last row.

If the last row itself must have a different height, then I would suggest removing it from the grid container and placing it underneath as a new element.

***NOTE*** also that the problem raised in the question applies only in the *implicit* grid. In the *explicit* grid, defining the height of the last row (or any row, for that matter) is simple and easy.

Comment: Certainly the last row does not change its size. I thought there was some mechanism to set the last row to another value different from the one set on **grid-auto-rows** So the final suggestion is totally valid but I also would like to know your opinion on @G-Cyr  'answer using the value **min-content** on **grid-auto-rows** which seems to be a direct solution.

Comment: `grid-auto-rows: min-content` is a good solution *IF*: (1) all your images are the same height. If not, you'll need to set a equal height on them so the rows are equal height, and (2) your target browsers supports `min-content`. You'll need to check and test: http://caniuse.com/#search=min-content

Comment: Also, `grid-auto-rows: min-content` in this case is essentially the same as `grid-auto-rows: auto`, which is the default setting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using   `grid-auto-rows: min-content;` is fine here . `grid-template-rows:50px;` will only set first row's height.

`height` or `max-height` could be used on `.photo-card` if necessary.

```css
.travel-photos {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  grid-gap: 20px 10px;
}

.travel-photos h1 {
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.photo-card>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.photos-footer {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">


</head>

<body>

  <section class="travel-photos">
    <h1>PHOTOS</h1>

    <div class="photo-card">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    </div>

    <div class="photo-card">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    </div>

    <div class="photo-card">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    </div>

    <div class="photo-card">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    </div>

    <div class="photo-card">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    </div>

    <div class="photo-card">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    </div>
    <div class="photo-card">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    </div>


    <div class="photos-footer">
      <button>MORE</button>
    </div>

  </section>





</body>

</html>
```